# Blurry vertical line even with GuidelineSet applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm drawing a vertical line in a custom control's `OnRender` method. I apply a `GuidelineSet` so that the line is aligned with the physical device pixels. Yet the line still appears blurry, and zooming into it shows anti-aliasing applied. What am I doing wrong here?

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    Pen axisPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
    if (axisPen.CanFreeze)
        axisPen.Freeze();

    double lineLength = RenderSize.Height + 1;
    double thick = axisPen.Thickness * 0.5;
    GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
    guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(thick);
    dc.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
    dc.DrawLine(axisPen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, lineLength));
    dc.Pop();
}
```

Comment: Do you have the scaling on your monitor set to anything? I don't see a problem but I have mine at 100%. WPF defines coordinates at 96 dpi and will scale it to anything larger at runtime.

Comment: I have two monitors, but I've been testing on a monitor with scaling set to 100%. I also told Windows 10 not to attempt to make blurry apps clear, in case that was screwing anything up.

Comment: There appear to be certain issues with multi-monitor, multi-DPI setups on Windows 10 where lines are anti-aliased even with guidelines applied. I didn't manage to sort out the various scenarios. This is also targeting .NET 4.5, which lacks some of the better multi-DPI support of later versions.